# Setting authorization section of multiple location elements in one web.config from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have two location elements in a single web.config file, and would like to change the authorization in the code behind.

The web.config location sections are like this:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="~">
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles=""/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="~/SubPage">
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles=""/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

From the code behind I would like to go through the location elements, and then make the changes to that specific location element.  For example, c# code behind would be:

```
Configuration myConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
ConfigurationLocationCollection locations = myConfig.Locations;
foreach (ConfigurationLocation location in locations)
{   
   if (location.Path = "~")
   {
     //define & clear the authorization section of the particular location element.
     //create and apply rule for allow in that authorization section.
     //create and apply rule for deny  in that authorization section.
     //save the change

   }

   if (location.Path = "~/SubPage")
   {
     //define & clear the authorization section of the particular location element.
     //create and apply rule for allow in that authorization section.
     //create and apply rule for deny  in that authorization section.
     //save the change

   }

}
```

I have tried several different things here, but I don't have one solution that actually works so far...  I need to consoldiate any change to the web.config in the root directory (~) (any change would have to be reflected in this file, not other files in the subpage).  Any recommended working solution to fill in the blanks?  The purpose is to allow admin users to make changes on an admin user interface to decide which users or windows groups on the internal network will be allowed to view the two locations, so I would particularly like to change the allowed roles from the code behind.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, abandoned trying to make all the changes on the same file, and instead simply opened a new configuration manager instance in each location.Path.

WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(location.Path), then applied the rules to each individual web.config at each location.  I couldn't centralize all the authorizations in one place, but at least it was working.

Comment: Could you please share the idea or code, that is working with you, actually I am in need of same thing now :)

Comment: http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/programmatically-update-authorization-170136.aspx